# Question about direct sum of groups 

Tags: group-theory

I have trouble understanding this question and its supposed answer.

> Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$. Prove that $A$ is a direct summand of $G$ if and only if there is a homomorphism $p:G \to A$ with $p(a)=a$ for all $a \in A$. Here we talk about internal direct sum.

When I see this, I was thinking, why do homomorphism of that ($p:G \to A$) implies it is a direct summand of $G$? That is strange. Considering simple application of homomorphism can give us whether a subgroup $A$ is a direct summand of $G$.

Any advice on how to prove this is most appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for $\Rightarrow$:

1. Prove that the map $$t: G \to A \oplus \text{ker}(p)$$ given by $$g \mapsto (p(g),p(g)g^{-1})$$ is a homomorphism of groups
2. Prove that $t$ is injective and surjective (i.e. an isomorphism)

Hint for $\Leftarrow$: Consider the projection $p: G = A \oplus B \to A$

Comment: ok. so... i have manage to prove that it is a homomorphism. injective and surjective then. So, this implies that $G\cong A\oplus ker(p$) where A has become direct summand of G with the map given above. thanks. i get it now. thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian has given you hints on how to prove this. Let me give you a bit of intuition for why the relation between direct sums and maps.

When you have a direct sum, $G=A\oplus B$, you have two pairs of maps that relate $A$, $B$, and $G$. You have projections $\pi_A\colon G\to A$ and $\pi_B\colon G\to B$ (with $\pi_A(a,b) = a$ and $\pi_B(a,b) = b$) and you have injections $i_A\colon A\to G$ and $i_B\colon B\to G$ (with $i_A(a) = (a,1_B)$ and $i_B(b) = (1_A,b)$, where $1_A$ and $1_B$ are the identities of $A$ and $B$, respectively). The maps are related by the property that $\pi_A\circ i_A = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $\pi_B\circ i_B = \mathrm{id}_B$.

If you identify $A$ with $i_A(A)$, then this translates exactly to the condition in the problem. So the problem is telling you that these conditions are in fact *characterized* by the existence of the maps. Why?

Consider the situation where you have a homomorphism $f\colon G\to A$ that is onto. If $B=\mathrm{ker}(f)$, then for each $a\in A$ you can pick an element $g_a\in G$ such that $f(g_a) = a$ (a pre-image). In general, these will not form a subgroup; sometimes, you can *pick* the elements cleverly enough so that they *will* form a subgroup, sometimes not. For example, if you map $C_{15}\to C_3$ (cyclic group of order 15 to cyclic group of order 3) by sending the generator $x$ to the generator $y$, then you can pick any of $1,x^3,x^6,x^9,x^{12}$ as $g_{1}$, any of $x,x^4,x^7,x^{10},x^{13}$ as $g_y$, and any of $x^2,x^5,x^8,x^{11},x^{14}$ as $g_{y^2}$. If you were to pick, say, $1$, $x^4$, and $x^{11}$ as you preimages, they don't form a group, but if you pick $1$, $x^{10}$, and $x^{5}$, then they *do* form a subgroup that is isomorphic to $C_3$. On the other hand if you take $C_4\to C_2$, again mapping generator to generator, the possible preimages of $1$ are $1,x^2$ and the possible preimages of $y$ are $x,x^3$. There is no way to pick an element of $\{1,x^2\}$ and an element of $\{x,x^3\}$ so that the two are a subgroup of $C_4$. So sometimes you can, sometimes you cannot.

When you *can*, if you let $\mathcal{A}$ be the subgroup of $G$ that is isomorphic to $A$ via the original map $p\colon G\to A$, then every element of $G$ will be written as an element of $\mathcal{A}$ and an element of $B=\mathrm{ker}(p)$. But in general this will not be a direct product, because you will have $(ab)(a'b') = a(ba')b' = aa'(a'^{-1}ba')b'$; unless $a'^{-1}ba'=b$ for all $b$, you don't get a direct product. So you it's not enough to be able to "retract" the projection, there's more needed.